# How do I turn a Fitec FS90R servo motor 90 degrees clockwise and anti-clockwise using a PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, servo, pic18

I have tried varying the duty cycle of the servo motor but it only turns 180 degrees clockwise and anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

You need some measurement device to read the angle, if you want to stick with that servo. With the angle you can implement a closed-loop transfer function to approach the angle you want.

Servos as the FS90R are ["continuously rotation servos"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_(radio_control)#Continuous-rotation_servos) and the control signals sets the **speed** (exactly: the driving current, giving the torque) and direction. For example, see [this fine explanation](https://firialabs.com/blogs/lab-notes/continuous-rotation-servos-with-python-and-the-micro-bit).

If you want to control the angle directly by the control signal, you need "the other" type of servo, described earlier in the linked Wikipedia page.